# Export SSRS report on Server instead of local machine

Tags: reporting-services

Could you please guide me the possible way to export SSRS Report(Excel) on Server not on Local machine?

Comment: Google for report subscriptions- they can run the report in different formats and put them on a file share.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways I know of using report manager:  1) Subscriptions and 2) Save as when you download.